# The image does not load as soon as my production server is up

Tags: javascript, html, webpack-dev-server, webpack-file-loader

I was watching a course that I spent js where they explain the use of webpack and its libraries, something new for me, I realized that the course is a little old and I have adapted some things to the current versions but nothing has worked with the image that does not load, I was giving several laps and I have not been able to achieve it, I would appreciate the help of anyone.
If you see the dirty code is so many tests and lines that I have put but have not worked, but I have left them commented.
NOTE: I am using a translator, my English is not very good.

if you need me to show you something additional, I will be happy to do so

the code doesn't seem to have any problem, but the image doesn't show up on my site, I feel it's the stupidest mistake in the world for not finding it myself.

I was trying what they indicated here in stackoverflow but it didn't help me, I left it there among the commented code.

webpack.config.js

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin       = require('html-webpack-plugin'); 
const MiniCssExtractPlugin    = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

// imgname = require("file-loader!./assets/logo.png");

const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [ new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin() ]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /styles\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /styles\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'html-loader',
                        options: { minimize: false }
                    }
                ]
            },

            // {
            //     test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot)$/,
            //     type: 'asset/resource',
            //     generator: {
            //         filename: './fonts/[name][ext]',
            //     },
            // },

            {
                // test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                // use: [
                //     {
                //         loader: 'file-loader',
                //         options: {
                //             esModule: false,
                //             name: 'assets/[name].[ext]'
                //         }
                //     }
                // ]
            },

            // {
            //     test: /.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
            //     type: "javascript/auto",
            //     use: [{
            //       loader: 'file-loader',
            //       options: {
            //         name: '[name].[ext]',
            //         outputPath: 'assets/fonts/',
            //         publicPath: '../fonts/'
            //       }
            //     }]
            // }
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            esModule: false,
                            name: 'assets/[name].[ext]'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
            
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: './index.html'
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css',
            ignoreOrder: false
        }),

        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: 'src/assets/fonts', to: 'assets/' }
            ]
        }),

        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: 'static' }
            ]
        })
    ]

}

webpack.prod.js

const HtmlWebPackPlugin       = require('html-webpack-plugin'); 
const MiniCssExtractPlugin    = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const MinifyPlugin            = require('babel-minify-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin              = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin }  = require('clean-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [ new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin() ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'main.[contenthash].js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { 
                test: /\.js$/, 
                exclude: /node_modules/, 
                use: [
                    'babel-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: /styles\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /styles\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'html-loader',
                        options: { minimize: false }
                    }
                ]
            },
            // {
            //     test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
            //     use: [
            //         {
            //             loader: 'file-loader',
            //             options: {
            //                 esModule: false,
            //                 name: 'assets/[name].[ext]'
            //             }
            //         }
            //     ]
            // }
            // {
            //     test: /.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
            //     type: "javascript/auto",
            //     use: [{
            //       loader: 'file-loader',
            //       options: {
            //         name: '[name].[ext]',
            //         outputPath: 'assets/',
            //         publicPath: '../'
            //       }
            //     }]
            // }
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            esModule: false,
                            name: 'assets/[name].[ext]'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }


        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: './index.html'
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
            ignoreOrder: false
        }),

        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                { from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets/' }
            ]
        }),

        new MinifyPlugin(),
        
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    ],

    output: {
        filename: 'main.[contenthash].js',
        clean: true,
     }
};


package.json

{
  "name": "webpack-inicial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Este es un cascaron de un proyecto de webpack",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "build:dev": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --port=8080"
  },
  "author": "José Hidalgo",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.20",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "babel-minify-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.1",
    "babel-preset-minify": "^0.5.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@formkit/auto-animate": "^0.8.0"
  }
}

index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>webpack</title>
</head>
<body>

    <img src="./assets/logo.png" alt="logo overwatch">

    <h1>asdasd</h1>

</body>
</html>
```